# How to create branch from main but without its commits and files?

Tags: git, github, branch

I have files in main branch and I wanted add new branch NEW_PROJECT so I can later on PR and merge it to main. The problem is that every time i create NEW_PROJECT from main branch I also get its files, and if I delete it they are still visable in commits.

Is there a way to create empty branch without commits that can be later on PR to main?

Comment: one way to do this would be squash. You will create new branch with old commits, yes. However you can 'squash' them into one to have cleaner history

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/how-do-i-squash-my-last-n-commits-together

Comment: I don't see the problem with branching off `main` in the usual way.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want any commits or files from main, you can create an empty root commit and then create a branch from the commit,

```
git branch foo $(git commit-tree -m "some message" 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904)
```

`4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904` is a special tree object that represents an empty directory. `git commit-tree` creates a commit that refers to the empty tree with the commit message `some message`. In other words, if you check out this commit, there will be no files or sub-directories. You can add and commit files based on it.

`git branch` creates foo from the commit.

This way, foo and main are two unrelated histories. Merging foo with main needs an option `--allow-unrelated-histories`.

If you find the special empty tree hash value hard to memorize, we can also use a command to make it,

```
git hash-object -t tree --stdin < /dev/null
```

It prints `4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904`.

But for most users, it's as rare a command as `4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904`. There's another method, which may be easier to memorize,

```
git init /path/to/bar
cd /path/to/bar
git commit --allow-empty -m "some message"
cd /path/to/your/repository
git fetch /path/to/bar main
# Or "git fetch /path/to/bar master" depending on the default branch name
# After fetch, the empty commit is stored in FETCH_HEAD
# Create foo from FETCH_HEAD so you don't have to know its exact hash
git branch foo FETCH_HEAD
# Remove /path/to/bar
rm -rf /path/to/bar
```

This method needs more steps, but they are more common commands.

If you know a commit (for example `abc123`) refers to the empty tree, you can also find the empty tree hash by

```
git rev-parse abc123^{tree}
# Or
git log -1 --pretty=%T abc123
```

Once you find out the hash of the empty tree, you can then make a tag on it so that you can reference the empty tree with a more friendly name.

```
git tag emptytree 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904
```

Now when you want to create a branch baz from the empty tree,

```
git branch baz $(git commit-tree -m "some message" emptytree)
```